# Need help for RegExp (in Flutter)

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I'm trying to filter a String list like:

```
List<String> names = ["NAM", "XYZ", "+QWE (HJB)", "+XYZ (NAM)", "(NAM)"];
```

While using regex I want to compare each String with a string that contains  "NAM" or "HJB" and print every string of names containing the filter string out. So in the end it would print out everything with "NAM" in it (also "+XYZ (NAM)", but without the special chars)

My code looks like this but either way I catch everything ("+QWE (HJB)")

```
regexp3 = RegExp(r'[a-zA-Z]+');
```

or Nothing

```
final regexp2 = RegExp(r'^\+.([a-zA-Z]+) \(([a-zA-Z]+).\).$');
```

because if I only filter with "NAM" (for example) it gives me an null error.

Complete code.

```
void main() async {
  List<String> names= ["TEX","TOL","+TEX (TOL)","+TOL (TEX)", "(NAM)"];
  List<String> filter = ["TEX", "TOL"];
  final regexp3 = RegExp(r'[a-zA-Z]+');
  for(var e in names){
    if(filter.contains(regexp3.firstMatch(e)!.group(0))) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Your example code is not in sync with problem description and is kind of unclear: do you mean to use `filter` items to build a regex checking for either `TEX` or `TOL` and as a result, get `['TEX','TOL','+TEX (TOL)','+TOL (TEX)']`? Then use `for(var e in names){ if (RegExp(filter.join("|")).hasMatch(e)) { print(e); }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing regex patterns is indeed giving us a slight nystagmus. However, it is important to be careful about the regex groups numeration. As far as I understand, you want to get the content of `group(1)` which is captured by the first parenthesis after `\+`.

To match the strings correctly I also removed a few `.` characters from the regex pattern.

Replaced the bang operator (`!`) with `?` and `??` in addition to provide safe default value instead of throwing errors on nulls.

Good luck!

```dart
void main() async {
  List<String> names= ["TEX","TOL","+TEX (TOL)","+TOL (TEX)", "(NAM)"];
  List<String> filter = ["TEX", "TOL"];
  final regexp3 = RegExp(r'^\+([a-zA-Z]+) \(([a-zA-Z]+)\)$');
  for(var e in names){
    var regroup = regexp3.firstMatch(e)?.group(1);
    if(filter.contains(regroup)) {
      print(e + '\t\t' + (regroup ?? ''));
    }
  }

}
```